# A modal inside a Map Function In ReactJs has error message

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, modal-dialog

I would like to ask question about some kind of grid gallery for a portfolio section. Each grid has a overlay which could be triggered by mouseover and the grids are generated by a map function and data in the grids are linked with a json file. The problem is that when I put a draft modal that I supposed it is for the grid , an error message showed "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggleModal' of undefined" for this tag . Thanks for any solution.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Modal from './Modal';

class Portfolio extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { isOpen: false };
  }

  toggleModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    if(this.props.data){
      var projects = this.props.data.projects.map(function(projects){
        var projectImage = 'images/portfolio/'+projects.image;
        return <div key={projects.title} className="columns portfolio-item">
          <div className="item-wrap">
           <a href={projects.url} className="open-popup" title={projects.title}> 
               <img alt={projects.title} src={projectImage} />
               <div className="overlay"> 
                  <div className="portfolio-item-meta">
                 <h5>{projects.title}</h5>
                     <p>{projects.category}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              <div className="link-icon"><i className="fa fa-link"></i></div>
            </a>
          </div>

          <button  onClick={this.toggleModal}>
            Open the modal
          </button>

          <Modal show={this.state.isOpen} onClose={this.toggleModal} >
            Here's some content for the modal
          </Modal>

        </div>
          
      })
    }

    return (
      <section id="portfolio">

      <div className="row">

         <div className="twelve columns collapsed">

            <h1>Check Out Some of My Works.</h1>

            <div id="portfolio-wrapper" className="bgrid-quarters s-bgrid-thirds cf">
                {projects}
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>

   </section>
    );
  }
}

export default Portfolio;
```

and the Modal.js is below:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Modal extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // Render nothing if the "show" prop is false
    if(!this.props.show) {
      return null;
    }

    // The gray background
    const backdropStyle = {
      position: 'fixed',
      top: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
      padding: 50
    };

    // The modal "window"
    const modalStyle = {
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      borderRadius: 5,
      maxWidth: 500,
      minHeight: 300,
      margin: '0 auto',
      padding: 30
    };

    return (
      <div className="backdrop" style={backdropStyle}>
        <div className="modal" style={modalStyle}>
          {this.props.children}

          <div className="footer">
            <button onClick={this.props.onClose}>
              Close
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Modal.propTypes = {
  onClose: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  show: PropTypes.bool,
  children: PropTypes.node
};

export default Modal;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused from this line:

```
var projects = this.props.data.projects.map(function(projects){
```

Since you used `this.toggleModal` inside this function, the `this` context is linking to this function, not the React component.

The solution is to use an arrow function like this:

```
var projects = this.props.data.projects.map((projects) => {
```

On a side note, it's not a good idea to define a variable inside a block and use it outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is my revised version, thanks. What should I do if I want to add next and previous function in modal in order to show next or previous project information? Thanks. I am sorry that I am new with React and Javascript.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Modal from './Modal';

class Portfolio extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { 
      isOpen: false,
      activeProjects:"",
      activeProjectImage:""
    };
  }

  toggleModal = (projects,projectImage) => {
    this.setState({activeProjects:projects, activeProjectImage:projectImage},() =>
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    }));
  }
  
  render() {
    if(this.props.data){
      var projects = this.props.data.projects.map((projects) => {
        var projectImage = 'images/portfolio/'+projects.image;
        return <div key={projects.title} className="columns portfolio-item">
          <div className="item-wrap">
           <a onClick={() => this.toggleModal(projects,projectImage)} className="open-popup" title={projects.title}> 
               <img alt={projects.title} src={projectImage} />
               <div className="overlay"> 
                  <div className="portfolio-item-meta">
                    <h5>{projects.title}</h5>
                    <p>{projects.category}</p>
                  </div>  
                </div>
              <div className="link-icon"><i className="fa fa-link"></i></div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      })
    }

    return (
      <section id="portfolio">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="twelve columns collapsed">
            <h1>Check Out Some of My Works.</h1>
            <div id="portfolio-wrapper" className="bgrid-quarters s-bgrid-thirds cf">
              {projects}
              <Modal show={this.state.isOpen} onClose={this.toggleModal} >
                <img alt={this.state.activeProjects.title} src={this.state.activeProjectImage} />
              </Modal>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export default Portfolio;
```